# Make DevExpress BarButtonItem Content two line

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, devexpress

I have a BarbuttonItem like this :

```
<dxb:BarButtonItem Name="abtn" Content="See New Items Added to Stocks" ItemClick="ItemClick" BarItemDisplayMode="Content"  />
```

This button looks like this :

> See New Items Added to Stocks

I want to make it look like  this

> See New Items < newline > Added to Stocks

How can I achieve that? Thanks.

Comment: I tried on a dxr:BackstageButtonItem and using Content worked fine.  Thanks for the edit :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will work :

```
<dxb:BarButtonItem Name="abtn" BarItemDisplayMode="Content" ItemClick="ItemClick">
      <dxb:BarButtonItem.ContentTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
     <TextBlock>
    See New Items<LineBreak/>
    Added to Stocks
    </TextBlock>
   </DataTemplate>
  </dxb:BarButtonItem.ContentTemplate>
</dxb:BarButtonItem>
```